# Windows Phone 8 and Microsoft Expression Blend 12

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, sdk, blend

I have installed Windows Phone 8.0 SDK with VS 2012 Express, and also a VS2013 Pro with Blend v12. How can I create windows phone mockups in the Blend, because I don't see this type of project in the Blend New Project dialog ?

Answer (score 0):

Since Windows Phone does not support WPF the way to built a Windows Phone app  using VS2012 version of Blend would be either as a standard Silverlight project or downloading and installing the Windows 8 Phone SDK. (link below)

http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk

Comment: I installed Windows phone 8.0 SDK, but I cannot find a Win Phone project.

Comment: Do you have more than one version of Blend installed?

Comment: The templates are usually located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\WindowsPhone\ProjectTemplates\WP80  Check to see if you any files there.

Comment: I see now, In VS2013 installation on my laptop, where I checked WinPhone SDK to be installed I have those templates, however, on my other computer where I have installed VS2013 without SDK, and installed SDK later (with VS2012 Express) I don't have those templates.